# Centre of navbar text, and aligning right. Also keep the navbar intact when reducing page size

Tags: html

So, my knowledge with regards to HTML5 coding and CSS is quite limited. I am trying to develop a website for my Occupational Health and Safety Consulting company.

I have started with the Navbar, logo and navigation buttons. However, I can't seem to have the text centred in the middle of the navbar vertically and have them blocked right horizontally. Also, I have noticed that as I increase and decrease the browser size, the text actually goes outside of the navigation bar.

I can't seem to post my code here. [Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MLLLJg) is a link to the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css"/>
<title>CMK Safety Solutions - Home</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="navigation-bar">
        <div id="navigation-container">
                <img src="images/logopng.png" height="120px"/>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Our Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Current Clients/Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is the CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.logo {
  float: right;
}
/* ~~ Top Navigation Bar ~~ */

#navigation-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
  height: 120px;
}

.navigation-bar {
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation-bar ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: right;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.navigation-bar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}

.navigation-bar li a {
  color: #808080;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: So you want the logo to be placed in the left and the navbar links to be vertically centered and placed in the right?

Comment: Yes that is right. It seems that Mulperi below got it right.

Comment: Do mark his answer as the correct solution if it helped you solve your issue. Cheers.

Comment: I have done that :)

Comment: Sweet man. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/mulperi/189so4Ln/

Use snippet below on the container to make it push navigation buttons to right and logo to left. Also everything middle vertically:

```
#navigation-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Also what I did was remove the static height from the container so now the buttons won't be pushed outside the container when the screen is smaller.

And that is actually something to think about. You can use [media query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) to check if the screen is smaller or larger than a specified min-width or max-width and apply different set of styles for that scenario. Like a column navigation for example like in my fiddle. 
Try shrinking the screen to see how the navigation links change orientation when the screen is smaller than 400px.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  .navigation-bar li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

As a side note, try to use [HTML5 semantic elements](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp) like `<nav>` for the navigation :)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. That seemed to do it. Does using HTML5 semantic elements help with SEO? I heard that on a YouTube tutorial? To do that I would not use div but instead rather nav?

Comment: It is a bit confusing to me the difference between using div and nav. Maybe you can explain it? I know that div breaks items up into different blocks.

Comment: nav, section, header, footer, they are all just divs but with different name to help - just like you said - with SEO and accessibility stuff.

Comment: Is there any way to PM you or ask for advice directly? I feel like I might have a lot of questions with regards to the design of my website.

Comment: You can contact me via my facebook page https://www.facebook.com/Mulperi/
But I suggest you study and fiddle around with Flexbox and semantic elements first, see this link for more information: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Here is a simple example fiddle how to use flexbox with navbar: https://jsfiddle.net/mulperi/abkmfhqL/

Comment: Another example using flexbox to make layout: https://jsfiddle.net/mulperi/g5rwf7bk/